# HELP! Should use an str_replace with an explode statement along with regex?

Tags: php, regex, string, explode

I have two strings

```
$string1 = "� 2~07225~ 3~0430~ 4~01254~ 5~0853~* 7~08064~ 8~0853~ 10~0776~."

$string2 = "from the start Lisa drafted the paper for the project."
```

I need an string (echo) output that should be as follows (with numbers superscripted):

"From the Start (07225) Lisa (0430) drafted (01254) the * (0853) paper (08064) for the * (0853) project (0776)."

should I use an `str_replace` with an `explode` statement along with regex?

***** are represented as invisible fill in adjective such as "blue" (853) paper and "science" (853) project.

Anyone up for the challenge?

I have spent countless hour trying to figure this out.

please remember php starts counting from 0...

JC

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like homework, so I'll give you the crucial pointers, not the code.

Splitting up the words is easiest and does indeed use explode:

```
$words = explode(" ", $string2);
```

The regex is rather simple too:

```
preg_match_all('#(\d+)~(\d+)~([*]?)#', $string1, $matches,
     PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

You basically will have to foreach over the $matches. You will find the word index there in [1] and the fill number in [2]:

```
foreach ($matches as $row) {

    list( , $word_index, $fill_number, $asteriskthingy) = $row;
```

To assemble the output string, you will need to:

- Get the $words from the $last_index to the current $word_index. Use `array_slice` here.
- Append the fill number.
- Or do whatever the `*` is supposed to mean. You didn't explain the logic behind that variation, so; no idea.

Comment: Please forgive me. The * represents an invisible word that shows up in the output as an asterisk. I need to make a correction: String1 one goes to word9 (not word10). I am sort of a newbie when it comes to php

Comment: thanks for the help. I made the necessary corrections to clarify what I am trying to do. Is the advice you gave still relevant?

Comment: webarto wrote: "I don't see the challenge."  How would you handle this?

Comment: Use a loop and array_slice for the source data as advised. -- Or what have you tried so far?